# Getting status code in AngularJS 1 on service call

Tags: angularjs, http-status-codes

Once the service call is done, I was able to see the status code in General, Response Headers in Chrome Dev Network tab for the production URL. But for the test environments, the status code is being displayed in  General but not in  Response Header.

1. Why the status code is not displayed in Response header for test Environments.
2. How to access status code from General Header in AngularJS.
3. headers().status in the transformResponse method is always fetching from Response header. So for test environments, I was not able to get the status code.
4. Any other way to get the status code in AngularJS, I tried passing 2nd param in the success Callback, but I don't get any value for the status code

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking "How to access the status code from the response in AngularJS", it should always be in the response body.

You can get it by writing the following code in your service:

```
      this.requestInformation = function() {
          return $http({
              method: 'GET',
              url: 'Your url'
          }).then(function (response) {
              console.log(response.status)
              return response; 
          })
      }
```

I hope that answered your question! Let me know if it works for you.